# strtotime; selecting certain days; and thursday (today) not working

Tags: php, strtotime

I thought I had this working great and then realized that today is a particular month where it gets complicated.

This is what I have:

```
<!-- determines first Wednesday and first Thursday of the month to echo something different than the rest of the days of the month. -->
<?php
$firstwed = strtotime("first Wednesday, first Thursday". date("F Y"));
$now = strtotime('today'); 

if( $firstwed == $now) {
  echo "Registration is closed until our next event!";
  // do something
} else {
  echo 'REGISTER AND PAY ONLINE HERE';
  // do something else
}
?>
```

But I also needed it target yesterday (Wednesday, but it happened to be last month).

And it doesn't even seem to be working if I just target today (Thursday).??

Basically, the story is, every first friday of every month, they have a meeting, and need registration to close the wednesday and thursday before; then re-open on Friday.

Please help and thank you so much!

*EDIT: Can anyone else help on this subject? I still haven't made any progress.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to understand,
if I understand correctly,
here is the enhance version with some simplification :-

```
$today = explode(',', date('d,D,t'));  // month day, week day, days in month
switch ($today[1])
{
  case "Wed":
    if (($today[0]+2 > $today[2]) || $today[0] <=7)
    {
      //closed
    }
  case "Thu":
    if (($today[0]+1 > $today[2]) || $today[0] <=7)
    {
      //closed
    }
    break;
}
```

Because no matter what, the month-day for first Wed / Thu will never exceed 7

Comment: I know, I'm sorry, It's getting complicated now.
I'll give this a try; will this also work if for intense:
The first Friday of a month lies on the first; then I will need to be targeting the Wednesday and Thursday before that which will lie in the previous month.

Answer (score 1):

Your version is actually comparing the SECOND thursday:

```
php > echo date('c', strtotime('first wednesday, first thursday'));
2011-12-08T00:00:00-06:00   <--- dec 8th = thursday, but not **THE** first thursday
php > echo date('c', strtotime('first wednesday'));
2011-12-07T00:00:00-06:00   <--- dec 7th = wednesday
php > echo date('c', strtotime('today'));
2011-12-01T00:00:00-06:00   <-- dec 1st = thursday <-- actual first thursday of the emonth
```

strtotime is pretty good at guessing what you want, but it's not infallible, and this is one of the cases where it's blowing up in your face. It's finding the "first thursday" that occurs AFTER today, not the first thursday of the month.

```
php > echo date('c', strtotime('first thursday december'));
2011-12-08T00:00:00-06:00
php > echo date('c', strtotime('thursday december'));
2011-12-01T00:00:00-06:00
php > echo date('c', strtotime('thursday'));
2011-12-01T00:00:00-06:00
```

Not particularly intuitive.

You'd be better off using formal DateTime calls to get the "day-of-week" of the actual FIRSt day of the current month, and see if it's a wed/thursday.